# JWT decode from assertion - Google sign in

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to implement account linking in Actions on Google (Using [this](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth?creation=no&oauth=code#implement_your_oauth_server))

I'm stuck at **Handle automatic linking** step in it. I'm getting `assertion` from the request when I try to decode it using [python-jose](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose/) library specified [over here!](https://jwt.io/)

```
from jose import jwt
key = "728f4016652079b9ed99861bb09bafc5a45baa86" # PUBLIC KEY OF GOOGLE from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
encoded = "ENCODED_ASSERTION"
decoded = jwt.decode(encoded, key, algorithms='RS256')
print (decoded)
```

when I run this code it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/backends/pycrypto_backend.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.prepared_key = RSA.importKey(key)
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 757, in import_key
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jay.patel/PycharmProjects/Prac/jwt.py", line 19, in <module>
    decoded = jwt.decode(encoded, key, algorithms='RS256')
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/jwt.py", line 135, in decode
    payload = jws.verify(token, key, algorithms, verify=verify_signature)
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/jws.py", line 77, in verify
    _verify_signature(signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/jws.py", line 264, in _verify_signature
    if not _sig_matches_keys(keys, signing_input, signature, alg):
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/jws.py", line 212, in _sig_matches_keys
    key = jwk.construct(key, alg)
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/jwk.py", line 61, in construct
    return key_class(key_data, algorithm)
  File "/Users/jay.patel/env372/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jose/backends/pycrypto_backend.py", line 74, in __init__
    raise JWKError(e)
jose.exceptions.JWKError: RSA key format is not supported
```

What am I doing wrong?? I've just used RS256 because it is specified in Google's public keys (available in [JWK](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs) or [PEM](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs) format)

**P.S.** 
When I try to decode the assertion [here](https://jwt.io/) with `RS256` algorithm it shows invalid signature error as shown in below image.

[image]

**Edit**
I came to know that I'm passing the wrong key, so now I'm using this code to generate public keys from certificate but it gives me this error.

```
initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not int
```

this is my code

```
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

certificate_text = open('certificate.txt', 'r').read()
certBytes = list(certificate_text.encode())
certificate = load_pem_x509_certificate(certBytes, default_backend())
publicKey = certificate.public_key()
```

and this is how my certificate.txt looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What am I doing wrong? (I've copied one of the certificates from [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs) and removed `\n` from it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with how you're handling the JWT.

The first is that what you're calling a "key" is actually a "kid" or "key ID". It references which key from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs you should be using. These keys rotate frequently, so you need to re-fetch them on occasion, and then use the "kid" to determine which one was used to sign it. The "key" itself isn't provided because that would be insecure (imagine sending a locked glass box, with the key taped to the top of it).

I suspect that the error message is deceptive. It isn't that RSA isn't supported, it is that the *format of the RSA key that you've provided* isn't supported. This makes sense - you haven't provided a key. [The documentation](https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jws/index.html#supported-algorithms) says RS256 is supported. Although there are no examples [the documentation on `verify()`](https://python-jose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jws/api.html#jose.jws.verify) says that the key can be a [JWK or JWK Set](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517), which is what Google provides at the certs URL, so you should just be able to provide those.

The reason the jwt.io manual decoding says the signature is invalid is... well... because given the information you've provided, it is. You have't given it a public key in the signature section (the blue part) that it can use to verify the other parts of the token, so it thinks it is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I've been surfing and I came to know that I'm passing the wrong key, but I'm stuck to generate public keys from the certificate, I tired `cryptography`, `OpenSSL.crypto` but they all give me same error `initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not int`

Comment: I've updated my question, kindly tell me am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try just using the JWK or JWK Set that Google sends? (The documentation on Jose suggests that it should work.)

Comment: I'm able to generate public key by using this command `openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in certificate.txt > certpubkey.pem`

Comment: Where are you getting the info that a PEM key is what is accepted?

Comment: I'm getting `jose.exceptions.JWTError: Signature verification failed.` when try to decode code by the public keys. currently, I'm passing whole value including  `--BEGIN PUBLIC KEY--` and `--END PUBLIC KEY--`. Is it correct?

Comment: The documentation I found says that the key needs to be a JWK or JWK Set, not a PEM. Unless you are seeing something else somewhere. The JWK version is the JSON notation one you posted at first that I mentioned in my answer. Also make sure it is the one that matches the Key ID specified in the JWT.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182428/discussion-between-jay-patel-and-prisoner).